# ignoring vertical space due to underbraces in cases environment

Tags: spacing, amsmath

In the following formula, I would like to change the rendering such that the lower end of the "cases" brace looks as if there were no underbraces. Is that possible? I already tried `\smash` and negative `\vspace`s to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\terma{\left( 1\!-\!e^{\frac{-\lambda_2^2}{2\alpha^2\lambda_3^2}}\right)}
\newcommand\termb{e^{\frac{-\lambda_1^2}{2\beta^2|\lambda_2\lambda_3|}}}
\newcommand\termc{\left( 1-e^{\frac{-\sum_i\lambda_i^2}{2c^2}}\right)}

\[
\mathcal V(\sigma)=
 \begin{cases}
     0    & \text{if $\lambda_2>0$ or $\lambda_3>0$,}\\
     \underbrace{\terma}_{A}
     \underbrace{\termb\vphantom{\terma}}_{B}
     \underbrace{\termc\vphantom{\terma}}_{C}
     &\text{else}.
 \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of `\smash` and `\vphantom` to get the desired effect. First we need to use a `\smash` to "flatten out" the contents. Then we use a `\vphantom` to get the brace to the correct height fir just the terms and not the underbraces. Finally we need to add an additional `\vphantom` in order to give the entire expression the correct height, such that following text will not be superimposed on it. In all the code would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\terma{\left( 1\!-\!e^{\frac{-\lambda_2^2}{2\alpha^2\lambda_3^2}}\right)}
\newcommand\termb{e^{\frac{-\lambda_1^2}{2\beta^2|\lambda_2\lambda_3|}}}
\newcommand\termc{\left( 1-e^{\frac{-\sum_i\lambda_i^2}{2c^2}}\right)}
\[
\mathcal V(\sigma)=
 \begin{cases}
     0    & \text{if $\lambda_2>0$ or $\lambda_3>0$,}\\
     \vphantom{\terma}
     \smash{\underbrace{\terma}_{A}}
     \smash{\underbrace{\termb\vphantom{\terma}}_{B}}
     \smash{\underbrace{\termc\vphantom{\terma}}_{C}}
     &\text{else}.
 \end{cases}
 \vphantom{\begin{cases}
     0    & \text{if $\lambda_2>0$ or $\lambda_3>0$,}\\
     \underbrace{\terma}_{A}
     \underbrace{\termb\vphantom{\terma}}_{B}
     \underbrace{\termc\vphantom{\terma}}_{C}
     &\text{else}.
 \end{cases}}
\]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: case braces]

Comment: you could reduce the "empty" space at the bottom a bit by using an explicit pair of "big" parentheses for `\terma` rather than `\left` and `\right`.  using `\exp` notation would also make those expressions more linear, but at the expense of making the line too wide; too bad -- that's some pretty nasty math to try to read without a magnifying glass.